# When is a List(T) collection "modified"?

Tags: c#, list, thread-safety

According to the documentation of the `List(T)` class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx a collection supports multiple readers. As long as the collection is not modified.

My question is when is a collection modified?

- When I change a value in the list? For example a `List<int>`, `intList[0] = 1;`
- When I add/delete something of the list? For example, `intList.add(1);`

Thanks for your help.

Paul

Comment: Yep, those are both examples of modifying the collection.

Comment: @JoranDenHouting There is no `list<T>` class, only a `List<T>` class. C# is case sensitive. Please be careful when you edit questions, the original question did not have that problem.

Comment: @hvd, I don't see the problem? In the edit history it's the same.. I did only include code-tags!

Comment: @JoranDenHouting The original version showed "For example a list, intList[0] = 1;" I see now the OP had `list<int>` in there, causing the `<int>` to be interpreted as invalid HTML and discarded, until you marked it as code.

Comment: @hvd thanks! My mistake, did change it again, waiting for approval of the edit. Sorry!

Comment: @JoranDenHouting Sorry, you're right, it was the OP's mistake, and you only exposed it. How about like this?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, lol, at the end it's only a good thing being that focused.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the edits. I should have used code tags. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **My question is when is a collection modified?**
>
> When I change a value in the list? For example a `List<int>, intList[0] = 1;`

Yes, changing the item does change the collection.

However, when your `T` from `List<T>` is a reference type, and you don't change the entire object (e.g. change only one class property value) the collection is not modified. e.g. consider a class `Foo` with `int` property `Bar`.

```
List<Foo> items = new List<Foo> { new Foo(), new Foo() };
```

Following code **does** modify the collection:

```
items[0] = new Foo();
```

And following **does not** modify the collection:

```
items[0].Bar = 10;
```

> When I add/delete something of the list? For example, intList.add(1);

It always modifies the collection.

Answer (score 2):

For a list, it counts as modified when you add or remove elements from the array OR you change the contents of an element, so both your examples do indeed "modify" the collection.

But as a sidenote: For an array, you effectively cannot "modify" the collection, in this context.

So we have a clear difference in behaviour between `List<T>` and a plain array of T.

For example, this code throws an exception:

```
var testList = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();

foreach (var i in testList)
{
    testList[0] = 1;
}
```

But this code does *not* throw an exception:

```
var testArray = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray();

foreach (var i in testArray)
{
    testArray[0] = 1;
}
```

**Changing a property of a reference type stored in an element**

Note that if you have a list of a reference type, and you change one of the properties of one of the list's elements, that does *not* count as modifying the collection.

So for example, given this class:

```
class Element
{
    public int Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The following code does NOT throw an exception:

```
List<Element> list = new List<Element>()
{
    new Element(),
    new Element()
};

foreach (var element in list)
{
    list[0].Value = 1;
}
```

The reason it doesn't count as modifying the collection is that you are not changing the contents of an element, since the reference itself remains exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And when I use a List<"some class">?  Some class contains an int field. That I change.  Example:  testList[0].intField = 2

Comment: @MatthewWatson Sure, as long as it's still clear which part of your answer applies to the question as asked, and which part is extra information. In your earlier version, I felt you drew far too much attention to those extra details, but re-reading your answer, that isn't a problem, at least not in what you have now. I'll remove my earlier comments as they don't apply any more.

Comment: @hvd Yes, I rearranged my answer in response to your comments.